# Filtering by Negation Crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

Here is a simple JSON data set

```
var data =  [
            {name: "Alex", type: "human", legs: 2},
            {name: "Lassie", type: "dog", legs: 4},
            {name: "Spot", type: "dog", legs: 4},
            {name: "Polly", type: "bird", legs: 2},
            {name: "Fiona", type: "plants", legs: 0},
            ]
```

I can create a crossfilter based on type such as:

```
typeDimension.filter("dog");
```

What about the negation of this...?

```
typeDimension.filter(not("dog"));
```

Is this possible using crossfilter...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. One way is to use the [`filterFunction` method on your dimension](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_filterFunction), and provide it a function that checks whether a given datum is not equal to dog. Here's a complete example:

```
var data =  crossfilter([
            {name: "Alex", type: "human", legs: 2},
            {name: "Lassie", type: "dog", legs: 4},
            {name: "Spot", type: "dog", legs: 4},
            {name: "Polly", type: "bird", legs: 2},
            {name: "Fiona", type: "plants", legs: 0},
            ]);
var typeDimension = data.dimension(function(d){ return d.type; });
var t = typeDimension.filterFunction(function(d){ return d != "dog"; });
```

You'll get the following output:

```
>> console.log(JSON.stringify(t.top(Infinity)));
>> [
    {"name":"Fiona","type":"plants","legs":0}
    {"name":"Alex","type":"human","legs":2},
    {"name":"Polly","type":"bird","legs":2}
   ]
```

Comment: This is really helpful.  Thank you.  I have one follow up question...I define a dimensions (dimensionA) and then apply a filter to dimensionA  (filterA) Next, I define another dimension (dimensionB) and apply a different filter (filterB).  It seems that I have to clear the first filter (FilterA) before applying the second filter (filterB).  CF seems as though it can only have one filter working at a time....despite applying these filters on different dimensions....is this the way that CF operates....??? Thanks in advance. Mark

Comment: Mark, it would be best to open up a new question for that. This way 1) @mdml will get credit for answering it 2) Other people with the same question will then be able to find the answer

Comment: @markthekoala: glad to help! And I'd be happy to try and answer your other question, but I agree with ninjaPixel that it probably should be made as another question.